# Reverting mistaken votes

Tags: support, voting

I voted to reject an edit by mistake in this question: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/25977/11256. Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

The edit proposal was still there, and I've applied it to the question now. The edit seemed to remove a tangential solicitation for a now-defunct Image Processing Area 51 proposal.

Comment: Thank you, Peter!

Comment: @MBaz You’re welcome.